# How to replace the exact match and not the substring in comma separated strings in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a column with comma separated values and I want to replace the exact matched value and not the substring.

current column value = 'ab,aba,ab,abc'

```
UPDATE table SET col1 = INSERT(col1, LOCATE('ab', 'ab,aba,ab,abc'), CHAR_LENGTH('ab'), 'BA') WHERE FIND_IN_SET('ab', 'ab,aba,ab,abc');
```

I expect the column value to be 'BA, aba, BA, abc'. But it is not working as expected.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are there spaces in between?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you concatenate a `','` at the start of the column and at the end of the column and replace all `','` with `',,'`, the replacement of all `'ab'`s can be done by searching for `',ab,'` and replacing it with `',BA,'`.
Finally remove the leading and trailing `','`:

```
UPDATE tablename 
SET col = REPLACE(
            TRIM(',' FROM REPLACE(CONCAT(',', REPLACE(col, ',', ',,'), ','), ',ab,', ',BA,')), 
            ',,', 
            ','
          )
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('ab', col);
```

Or, if you want to pass `'ab'` and `'BA'` as parameters:

```
UPDATE tablename 
SET col = REPLACE(
            TRIM(',' FROM REPLACE(CONCAT(',', REPLACE(col, ',', ',,'), ','), CONCAT(',', 'ab', ','), CONCAT(',', 'BA', ','))), 
            ',,', 
            ','
          )
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('ab', col);
```

Replace `?1` with the string that you want to replace (`'ab'`) and `?2` with the replacement string (`'BA'`).

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=28cded4a6a5c4e16003a4b53a1082497).

Comment: this will not replace if there are 2 occurrences of 'ab' at the end ?
Example - 'ab,aba,ab,abc,ab,ab'

Comment: @VKS i see that now, but it is not because they are at the end. This happens to all adjacent 'ab's and it is a limitation of REPLACE(). I will edit.